# React Forms and Events

Tags: reactjs

I have a search form with a few inputs the user can enter data into and some buttons on the right hand side that toggle the search. Underneath everything is the main 'search' button. What happens when the user hits return or enter in any of the inputs is on of my toggle buttons onClick handlers always fires and I don't know why. I recreated the gist of this in fiddle/code here:

```
    class Sample extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('handle search called');
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('handleClick called');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="filterRow">
          <div className="filterColumn1">
            <label style={{"display":"block"}}>
              Name:
              <input type="text" name="name" />
            </label>
            <label>
              Id:
              <input type="text" name="id" />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="filterColumn2">
            <button key="sth" onClick={this.handleClick}>
              do something
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          SEARCH
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Sample/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugd9v9mk/25/)

Question: Why does the click handler on that button fire when you hit enter or return in the inputs? How come its not the handleSubmit which is the onsubmit of the form?

Comment: `onSubmit` has `handleSearch` attached that's why `handleSubmit` is not called :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit `Enter` this triggers your button with `submit` type (that's just natural behavior of forms not sure why). Your button `onClick` handler (`handleClick`) has `e.preventDefault()` called which prevents further bubbling of an event and that's why `handleSubmit` is not getting triggered.

If you change button type to `type="button"` then `Enter` will not trigger your button onClick handler.

Btw. on your example `onSubmit` has `handleSearch` as event handler but I guess you meant `handleSubmit`.

Comment: thanks fixed that error in the code your assumption was correct. I had no idea re: adding `type="button"` thank you!